# Java 8 streams: conditional Collector

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I want to use Java 8 streams to convert a List of String values to a single String. A List of values like "A", "B" should return a String like "Values: 'A', 'B' added". This works fine, however I want to change the Pre- and Postfix depending on the amount of values. For example, if I have a List of only "A" I want the resulting String to be "Value 'A' added".

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add("A");
    values.add("B");
    values.add("C");
    List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();
    value.add("A");
    System.out.println(log(values));
    System.out.println(log(value));
  }
  public static String log(List<String> values){
    return values.stream()
                 //.filter(...)
                 .map(x -> "'" + x + "'")
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(",","values:"," added"));

  }
}
```

Is there a way to change the Collctor, depending on the size of the resulting List? Then I could do something like

```
.collect(Collectors.joining(",", size = 1 ? "Value " : "Values: "," added"));
```

I would prefer a single stream operation without an intermediate List result. I also do not know the result beforehand, because I filter the stream.

Edit: I ended up using Eugene's suggestion. What I wanted to do is find the differences between two Lists and return the differences in human readable form. Works nicely!

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class HelloWorld
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<String> oldValues = new ArrayList<>();
    oldValues.add("A");
    oldValues.add("B");
    oldValues.add("C");
    List<String> newValues = new ArrayList<>();
    newValues.add("A");
    newValues.add("C");
    newValues.add("D");
    newValues.add("E");
    System.out.println(HelloWorld.<String>log(oldValues, newValues, " deleted"));
    System.out.println(HelloWorld.<String>log(newValues, oldValues, " added"));
  }

    public static <T> String log(List<T> first, List<T> second, String postfix) {
        return  (String) first
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> !second.contains(x))
                .map(x -> "'" + x.toString() + "'").
                collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                    list -> {
                        if (list.size() == 1) {
                            return "Value " + list.get(0) + postfix;
                        }
                        if (list.size() > 1) {
                            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
                            for (Object object : list) {
                                strings.add(object.toString());
                            }
                            return "Values: " + String.join(",", strings) +  postfix;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }));
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Value 'B' deleted
Values: 'D','E' added
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it via:

```
 return values.stream()
            .map(x -> "'" + x + "'")
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                    list -> {
                        if (list.size() == 1) {
                            return "value" + list.get(0);
                        }
                        if (list.size() > 1) {
                            return String.join(",", list);
                        }
                        return "Nothing found";
                    }));
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the `StringJoiner` used by the `joining()` collector only allows an alternative representation for the “no values” case, but not for the single value case. To add that feature, we have to track the count manually, e.g.

```
public static String log(List<String> values) {
    return values.stream()
                 //.filter(...)
                 .collect(
                         () -> new Object() {
                             StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("', '", "'", "' added");
                             int num;
                             String result() {
                                 return num==0? "No values added":
                                                (num==1? "Value ": "Values ")+sj;
                             }
                         },
                         (o,s) -> { o.sj.add(s); o.num++; },
                         (o,p) -> { o.sj.merge(p.sj); o.num+=p.num; }
                 ).result();
}
```

This is quiet complicated, but a “clean” solution; it would even work with parallel streams, if ever needed.

Example

```
System.out.println(log(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")));
System.out.println(log(Arrays.asList("A")));
System.out.println(log(Collections.emptyList()));
```

```
Values 'A', 'B', 'C' added
Value 'A' added
No values added
```

Comment: oh damn, this is nice, this anonymous object seems to create the "complicated" part, otherwise I find it beautiful. One small-ish disadvantage is that it would not compile under eclipse, but it's eclipse issue here...

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to understand what's happening and then report back. What is the difference/advantage over Collectors.collectingAndThen(...) like in the post of Eugene?

Comment: Well, `collectingAndThen`, as the name suggests, collects everything into a `List` before performing the actual string operation in the postfix action. Since there is not much happening in the stream before that, the postfix action would even work without the stream operation, `return values.isEmpty()? "Nothing found": values.size()==1? "Value '"+values.get(0)+"'": "Values '"+String.join("', '", values)+"'";`. If you have actual stream operations like filtering, then `collectingAndThen` has the disadvantage of needing the temporary space for the collected `List`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your example worked! However, I went with Eugene's way, as it's easier to understand and better fitting to my usecase (which uses generic Lists). I will post my final code later, thank you very much for the code example and explanation!

Answer (score 2):

One core idea of streams is to have a look at the contained elements individually, possibly in parallel. There are aggregate operations (like `count`) that consider all (remaining) elements of a stream. The `collect` method also is an aggregate, in the sense that it consumes all elements. However, only after it is finished the exact number of items is known.

In your case I would collect the middle part of the string (comma separated list of elements) and add the prefix `"Value"` or `"Values"` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. What's the easiest way to get the numbers of elements? A count in the map method, or is there any easier way? I could also count the separators but that's kinda unsafe (a value could contain a separator).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you first find the elements you wish to join, and then join them (after you find their count):

```
public static String log(List<String> values) {
    List<String>
        elements = values.stream()
                       //.filter(...)
                         .map(x -> "'" + x + "'")
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    String joined = String.join (",", elements);
    return (elements.size () == 1 ? "value " : "values:") + joined + " added";
}
```

It doesn't sound like a good idea to count the elements via some side effect of one of the intermediate `Stream` methods.

Comment: Thank you, definitely a good option (I don't know why I did not think about that).

Answer (score 2):

And another interesting option probably would be this:

```
public static String log(List<String> values) {
    Spliterator<String> sp = values.stream()
            .map(x -> "'" + x + "'")
            .spliterator();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Value = ");

    sp.tryAdvance(x -> sb.append(x));
    if (sp.tryAdvance(x -> {
        sb.replace(5, 6, "s ");
        sb.append(",").append(x);
    })) {
        sp.forEachRemaining(x -> {
            sb.append(",").append(x);
        });
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

The advantage is that you don't need to collect to a `List` to further append each of them separately.

Comment: `sp.tryAdvance(sb::append)`. The disadvantage is that the code is hard to maintain, i.e. the `sb.replace(5, 6, "s ")` has to be kept in sync with the `"Value = "` used some line above. And it wouldn’t support parallel processing, if ever needed…

Comment: I'm upvoting because it's always nice to see spliterators being used, but oh man...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner agreed on the `oh man` part, I only took it as *can it be done at all?*

Comment: Now I'm gonna be mean with you... What if instead of values (plural) and value (singular), you have people (plural) and person (singular)? This is just for fun...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner a different replace in the `StringBuilder`... But your point is understood and plz be like that more often, this is why Im here in the first place. Thx :)