# How can I concatenate string elements from list in java8 based on their amount?

Tags: java-8

I have the following structure:

```
class MyClass {
    String name;
    String descr;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Now I have a List of those objects and I want to print the name from the object above if the list contains any of those elements.

This is my code so far:

```
List<MyClass> list = getList();

if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println(list.get(0).getName());
} else {
    System.out.println("list is empty");
}
```

This will work when the `list` contains only one element. Now I need to improve it and consider an example when there is more than one element - in that case I need to print all names, comma separated.

For example the output should be:

When there are 3 elements:

```
name1,name2,name3
```

when there's one element:

```
name1
```

and when there's none:

```
list is empty
```

what's the most efficient way of implementing it?

Comment: Holger had recently posted a great way to do it... but it will not compile with eclipse compiler; other than that it's awesome https://stackoverflow.com/a/48281783/1059372

Comment: @Eugene that was for the special case of changing the single-element representation. This question is about the empty stream representation, [which is much simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46101849/2711488).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Collectors.joining` combined with `Collectors.collectingAndThen`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

...

String res = 
    list.stream()
        .map(c -> c.name)
        .collect(collectingAndThen(joining(","), s -> s.isEmpty() ? "list is empty" : s));
```

If you want to take in account the option when the list is null, you could do:

```
String res = 
    Optional.ofNullable(list).map(l -> l.stream()...).orElse("list is empty");
```

but to be honest I would use an if statement beforehand:

```
if(list == null || list.isEmpty()) { 
    return "list is empty"; 
} else { 
    return list.stream().map(c -> c.name).collect(joining(","));
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, can you just tell me how I could assign the output string to a variable? I want to put it in some variable, for example `String output` and then use this output somewhere else. How could I do it?

Comment: one more thing though - what if list is null? How could i put the `list is empty` message then?

Answer (score 5):

You also can use the built-in class `StringJoiner` to simplify your code as following code:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
joiner.setEmptyValue("list is empty");

list.forEach(it -> joiner.add(it.getName()));

System.out.println(joiner);
```

Comment: now this is awesome! did not know about `setEmptyValue`

Comment: @Eugene I also just used it recently in my own project, :)

Comment: @holi-java what about the situation when the list is null? how can I prevent it and insert the `list is empty` string when it happens?

Comment: @randomuser1 hi, you can just add `if(list!=null) list.forEach(..)`.